# How to filter the data from API json using ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I would like to have a search bar that filters the results I tried to do it but it does not work. When I'm looking for something, nothing happens, no mistake, so I'm wrong, but I do not know what, I'm new to typescript and I ask for help. Thanks in advance

```
Home.html
---------
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="filterItems()"
                 [showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel" (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)"></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemClick(item.id)">
      <h1>{{item.id}}</h1>
      {{item.title}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
Home.ts
-------
export class HomePage {

  public items:any;


  constructor(public http:HttpClient) {
    this.loadData();
  }
  searchTerm: string ;
  loadData() {
    let data:Observable<any>;
    data = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
    data.subscribe(result => { 

      this.items = result;
      this.filterItems= this.items;
    })
  }

filterItems(ev:any){ 
  this.loadData();
  const val = ev.target.value;
  this.filterItems = this.items.filter(item =>  
    {
      item.titre.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    })
}

itemClick(itemid:number){
  alert(itemid);
}

}
```

Comment: plz help....................

Answer (score 0):

so you can do this in your html

```
<ion-searchbar [formControl]="searchTerm"></ion-searchbar>
```

Then in your .ts file declare before the constructor

```
public searchTerm: FormControl;
```

Then inside your ngOnInit, have this function that listens to user input and waits a while before filtering

```
this.searchTerm.valueChanges
.pipe(debounceTime(700))
.subscribe(search => {
  this.items = this.filterItems(search);
});
```

Then your final method for the filter

```
filterItems(search) {
 this.items = this.filterItems;
 return this.items.filter(item => {
   return item.titre.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1 
 });
}
```

I hope this helps